# What's the equivalent of CanLoad guard for standalone components?

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

Before Angular 15, I used SCAM pattern in order to have one module per component/directive/pipe.

My app contains many lazy loaded pages (one module per page) with a CanLoad guard to prevent lazy loading (feature flags, ...).

Since Ng 15 (I'm on 15.0.4), I replaced all of my `loadChildren` by `loadComponent` (so, each pages became a standalone component). But... As I saw [there](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/45705) :

> CanLoad guards do not apply to loadComponent. canActivate
> should be used instead, just like you would do if it were simply

Problem : CanActivate doesn't prevent loading if needed. So now, all of my pages are loaded :(.

Is there a way to keep the "CanLoad" functionnality, but for loadComponent ?

Thanks !

**EDIT** : I tried with "canMatch" : It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Is it really a problem that all your components are load ? They aren't instantiated

Comment: In fact, It's not really a "problem" as a CanActivate prevents instanciation. But, if we think like this, CanLoad has no interest, same for custom preloading strategy. 

IMO, If 10 components will never be instanciates : why fetch them ?

Comment: btw `CanLoad` guards are deprecated since 15.1, have you tried `CanMatch` guards ?

Comment: Yes I've seen but haven't tried yet... on my way

Comment: I just tried: it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

I'm quoting the source code here :

```
  // Note that `canLoad` is only checked as a condition that prevents `loadChildren` and not
  // `loadComponent`. `canLoad` guards only block loading of child routes by design. This
  // happens as a consequence of needing to descend into children for route matching immediately
  // while component loading is deferred until route activation. Because `canLoad` guards can
  // have side effects, we cannot execute them here so we instead skip preloading altogether
  // when present. Lastly, it remains to be decided whether `canLoad` should behave this way
  // at all. Code splitting and lazy loading is separate from client-side authorization checks
  // and should not be used as a security measure to prevent loading of code.
```

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/cc286be7af31c7f999d6c469d3fd8f9becb28ce7/packages/router/src/router_preloader.ts#L113C32-L120)

So don't expect `canLoad` to working with `loadComponent()`.

`canMatch()` should be working though.